# Laravel's Eloquent. One/many to many of different models (types)

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent, relationship, has-many-polymorphs

I've got a model that can be related to arbitrary number of items (other models). What is the best way to retrieve those as an array/collection of items of their types, e.g.

```
$basket = Basket::find(1);
dd($basket->items); // [Banana, Yoghurt, Bread, Bread, Ham, Cheese, Cheese]
```

Table: `basket`

```
| id      | int |
| user_id | int |
```

Table: `basket_items`

```
| id        | int    |
| basket_id | int    |
| item_id   | int    |
| item_type | string |
```

Models: `Basket`, `Banana`, `Yoghurt`, `Bread`, `Ham`, `Cheese`

Where I've got so far is: I can not use Eloquent's relations here since `items` method is referencing multiple models. The question is: can I (probably don't see how)?

As a plan-B I'd just implement that `Basket::items` method issuing a query and then fetching each and every model and hydrating them. I wonder if there a better way of dealing with that.

Comment: Why do you have separate models for each of your products?

Comment: Yes and no :) I mean that's an artificial example that I made up not to disclose actual stuff im working on, so for the matter of this example in order to describe technical problem the answer is yes

Comment: $basket->items  = $basket->bananas->concat($basket->apples)->concat($basket->someOtherRelation);

Comment: Yep, I was thinking about that as well. Thank you for a proposal, though! I should've described the issue a bit in more details. I will need to paginate over related items as well. Solution without having Laravel/Eloquent would be `select * from basket_items where basket_id = ? order by ``order`` offset 0 limit 10`. Then in application group by type, batch-retrieve by id, hydrate, put in a proper order (again in the application). So the drawback of what you've proposed is that I will have to deal with that pagination in a very quirky way, so that'd be my plan-C, actually.

Comment: Oh, I think I get that now, have a look at polymorphic relations. It allows you to have a relation that uses different models as if it was a single type: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Comment: Yep, it sounds like it should do the trick, but still, how to I enforce `morphTo` act on a pivot table `basket_items`? I've spent around 3-4 hours today trying to figure that out and still have no clue :(

Comment: It seems like I need something like `morphToThrough` in this case...